# Add an app to list of content providers of attachment to email?

Tags: java, android

I made a color picker that stores color as bitmap and then saves it as 50x50 PNG file. I'd like Gmail's "Attach" button to recognise my app as content provider like Gallery and QuickPix (examples). I can't find anything about it. Could you help me?

Comment: Implement a `DocumentsProvider`. Or, possibly, implement an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` `Activity`.

Comment: Any links, tutorials?

Comment: For ACTION_GET_CONTENT method :(

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider.html